# Flutter GridView ListTiles appear below scroll container

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a Flutter scrolling GridView builder that looks like it renders the ListTiles below the Container the GridView is placed in. It appears it renders placeholder grid list tiles even when they are not within the Container bounds.

It looks like for some reason that the GridView ListTiles appear  outside (below) the parent container.

In this example the GridView is placed within a Container that is then placed as a child under a parent Scrollbar that is a child widget in a Column. The GridView appears to render the grid ListTiles (renders the background Tile color but not the Tile contents) outside its parent container, appearing as Tiles under the other child widgets of the parent Column widget.   See screen grabs below.

Grid List tiles under the Container

[image]

When I scroll the list up the shadow Tiles appear in the GridView with the Tile contents.

[image]

When I scroll back the Tiles below the GridView appear below?/under? the other widgets in the parent Column. See first image the colored area under the "Bye" text widget.
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll5/models/task_model.dart';

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class ScrollListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<TaskCard> _list;

  ScrollListWidget({Key? key})
      : _list = [],
        super(key: key);
  const ScrollListWidget.withList(
    List<TaskCard> list, {
    Key? key,
  })  : _list = list,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollListWidget> createState() => _ScrollListStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _ScrollListStatefulWidgetState extends State<ScrollListWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(height: 240, child: GridView.builder(
     shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: widget._list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => WordTile(
              widget._list[index].taskName(), widget._list[index].daysEffort()),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 4,
         ),
    ));
  }
}

class WordTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String word;
  final int score;

  const WordTile(this.word, this.score, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(.4), title: Text(word));
  }
}`
```

GridView within a Container contained within a Scrollbar and Column

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
  // by the _incrementCounter method above.
  //
  // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
  // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
  // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
      // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
      // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
      // in the middle of the parent.
      child:
      Column(children: [
      Scrollbar(
        controller: _scrollController,
        thickness: 8,
        interactive: true,
        thumbVisibility: true,
        child:ScrollListWidget.withList(_taskList)
      ),
      Text("Bye",style: TextStyle())])),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add)));
  // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
}`
```

Comment: Could you please explain us what you want / desire output?

Comment: I'd like the scrolling grid view to only be visible within its container. The above code the gridview looks like it pre-draws ListTiles below (outside) the container holding the gridview. Ie, ListTiles are rendered over the top of widgets below the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Ok after exploring some options it seems the issue only appears when using a ListTile directly in the grid list. If I embed the ListTile within a Card widget the problem goes away.